# Iterating through DictReader

Tags: python, loops, csv, dictionary

I have read a csv file using,

```
with open('test.csv', newline='') as csv_file:
        #restval = blank columns = - /// restkey = extra columns +
        d = csv.DictReader(csv_file, fieldnames=None, restkey='+', restval='-', delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
```

I would like to iterate through the created dictionary to find blank values within the csv. 
I have tried:

```
for k, v in d.items()
#Do stuff
```

However I get the error: **AttributeError: 'DictReader' object has no attribute 'items'**

Is it right in saying that the values stored in **d** is a dictionary of dictionaries?

Coming from C# I would have stored the csv in a multidimensional array with a nested for loop to iterate through the values. Unfortunately I'm still new to Python - any help + explanations will be appreciated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`DictReader()` produces a *sequence* of dictionaries, not just one dictionary.

```
for row in d:
    for k, v in row.items():
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to first iterate over the dict getting each row, and then iterate over the items in each row:

```
for row in d:
    for k, v in row.items():
        # Do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

We also can try:

```
with open('test.csv', newline='') as csv_file:
        #restval = blank columns = - /// restkey = extra columns +
        d = csv.DictReader(csv_file, fieldnames=None, restkey='+', restval='-', delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        data = list(d)

for row in data:
        for key,val in row.items():
                print(key)
                print(val)
```